# F11 key no longer works (with or without fn)

Tags: keyboard

The solution is probably out there but I don't know the terms to google to find it! I was using <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>F11</kbd> and <kbd>F12</kbd> to turn the volume up and down on my Mac. When I press them now, either on their own, holding down for example <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>, or with <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>f11</kbd>, I get the grey volume box pop up on the screen but with the 'no' symbol underneath, as in the attached screenshot.[image]

I checked in system preferences and I haven't' selected 'use as normal function keys'. It's also not that there is no sound, just that I can't change the volume. How did I manage this?! And how do I undo it? Thanks!

Comment: What is your sound output set to? Internal speakers, or something else?

Comment: @Tetsujin it's set to MacBook Air speakers, so built-in